# Having jQuery inside of an iframe modify the parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a page which has an iframe.

in the iframe, I want jQuery to remove an element from the patent page, so I'm trying:

```
parent.$('#attachment-134').remove();
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 7):

Should be:

```
$(parent.document).find('#attachment-134').remove();
```

This of course only remains true, if the iframe and the parent have the identical **domain**. Otherwise the SOP (Same Origin Policy) would deny the access.

Example: http://jsbin.com/eqise5

Comment: Thanks they are at the same domain. I tried the above but it had no effect.

Comment: @AnApprentice: is jQuery available in the iframe ?

Comment: It is, but it looks like jquery in the parent and iframe along with fancybox is breaking things. I'll mark this as answered and start a new question. Thanks!

Comment: @AnApprentice: I added an example anyway.