# jquery trigger in iframe and action in parent frame

Tags: jquery

I have a simple  setup of as  such:

```
<div id="main_area">
<iframe src="mydearframe.php" . . . ></iframe>
...
...
...
<div id="stuff_to_do" ></div>
<div>
```

In the **mydeaframe.php** I have a button. Once that button is clicked, I want to do things in the **stuff_to_do** DIV which is in the mother/parent document, with JQUERY.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as these files are on the same domain, thus following `Same Origin Policy`.  You should be able to reference this from the iframe as

```
$(parent.document).find('#stuff_to_do')
```

This question is quite similar [Having jQuery inside of an iframe modify the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942382/having-jquery-inside-of-an-iframe-modify-the-parent-window)

Comment: I have this error: "Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.". Anny sugestion? :D